# how to pivot multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table structure !

```
create table t(floor int,apt int)
insert into t values(1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(2,5),(2,6),(2,7)
```

I want to get like this!

```
floor   room1   room2   room3
1       1       2       4
2       5       6       7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[More on pivot here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

1.you need to use [Row_number()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) partition by floor to get row then pivot to get your requirement

```
select p.floor,p.[1] as room1,p.[2] as room2,p.[3] as room3 from
(
select floor,apt,row_number() over(partition by floor order by apt) as rn from #t) as t

pivot
( 
min(t.apt)
for t.rn in([1],[2],[3]) 
)as p;
```

## [See in Action](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15312)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in this case.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT floor,
           apt,
           NumberedApt = 'room' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
               (PARTITION BY floor ORDER BY apt) AS NVARCHAR(100))               
    FROM   t   
) AS OrderApts
PIVOT (MAX(apt) FOR Numberedapt IN (room1, room2, room3)) AS PivotedApts
```

Here is and [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17715/3) of the above working.

If you are going to get many more 'room' columns then you might want to consider using a dynamic pivot, but they can be inefficient due to not having a query plan.